# How to compare items in two observables and then filter based on matches in RxJava2?

Tags: observable, rx-java2

How to compare items in two observables and then filter based on matches in RxJava2?

I'm attempting to compare two observables. Both consist of Server objects with an id and a server_address.

The first observable represents the current server objects peristed in a database.
`Observable1 = [{"id":1, "server_address": "10.1.1.1},{"id":2, "server_address": "10.2.2.2},{"id":3, "server_address": "10.3.3.3}]`

The second observable was created from a REST request from the user of server objects they would like to "add"/"insert" into the database.
`Observable2 = [{"id":4, "server_address": "10.1.1.1},{"id":5, "server_address": "10.4.4.4}]`

I only want to add/insert new servers that do NOT match an existing server_address that is already in the db. For example, if the server_address field from any of the items in Observable2 matches a server_address from any of the items in Observable1, then I want to filter these out and just have the truly new/unique server_address items left in Observable2.

In the case of the example above, I'd need logic that would filter out the server with the "id" of 4, because an item with that server_address already exists in the db. So I want to filter out item number 4 but keep item number 5. I will then insert item 5 into the database.

The question is, what operation can I use in RxJava2 to accomplish this? I've seen many things about zip or combine, but I'm not really sure that's what I want here.

Comment: To clarify, are these observables emitting a single list of items or each item individually?

Comment: Each item in the list is what is being emitted. Observable1 will emit three items from the database. And Observable2 will emit two items.. Also...what happens if the database is empty and there is a query on it? Will the rest of the logic fall to the wayside? I assume if there are no items in the observable (nothing to emit) then we can't perform operations that would combine it with another observable that does emit items, can we?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get this to work in a pure reactive way, but given your specification, it's probably more complicated than using a different approach: First get all the things you want to remove, and then filter `Observable2` using that.

Take this as pseudo-code, as I'm not exactly sure what you want to do (nor in which language you are doing it), but it should serve somehow:

```
allServers = observable1
    .map(s -> s['address'])
    .toList()
    .blockingGet() // out of the reactive world for a bit
    .toSet()

observable2
    .filter(s -> !allServers.contains(s['address']))
    .forEach(s -> doWhateverYouWantWith(s))
```

If you really want to do it 100% reactive, you'll probably need a way to distinguish from which observable you are coming from, merge the results, group by the address, and then filter. Again, in pseudo code, and assuming you have `Map`s representing each element:

```
observable1
    .map(s -> s + {'source': 'db'})
    .merge(observable2.map(s -> s + {'source': 'request'})
    .groupBy(s -> s['address'])
    .flatMap(group -> group.take(1))
    .filter(s -> s['source'] == 'request')
    .forEach(s -> doWhateverYouWantWith(s))
```

This works because in each group, you'll have either:

- only a 'db' element (which will be filtered out)
- both a 'db' and a 'request' element (which will be filtered out because 'db' always come first)
- only a 'request' element (which will pass the filter)

Comment: I'm being VERY creative with the syntax because I don't want to make the response too verbose w/o knowing more about your particular objects... Hope it helps anyway. If you give more details I can figure out a snippet that more closely resembles what you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your observables are emitting a list of items, you probably want to perform the filter operation on the collection, rather than the observable. There are a few ways to do this. You can achieve this with a simple flatMap + map, or with combineLatest/zip as you mentioned.

Examples are written in Kotlin.

```
val observable1 = Observable.just((1..10 step 2).toList()) // Odd integers between 1 and 10
val observable2 = Observable.just((1..10).toList()) // Integers between 1 and 10
```

**Flatmap + map**

```
observable1.flatMap { result1 ->
    observable2.map { result2 -> result2 - result1 }
}.subscribe { println(it.toString()) }
```

**CombineLatest**

```
Observable.combineLatest<List<Int>, List<Int>, List<Int>>(
    observable1,
    observable2,
    BiFunction { result1, result2 ->
        result2.filter { item ->
            !result1.contains(item)
        }
    })
    .subscribe { println(it.toString()) }
```

**Zip**

```
Observable.zip<List<Int>, List<Int>, List<Int>>(
    observable1,
    observable2,
    BiFunction { result1, result2 ->
        result2 - result1
    })
    .subscribe { println(it.toString()) }
```

All of these output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Alternatively, if you want to use RxJava's filter operator and emit each item individually you can use flatMapIterable to transform the list into a stream of items and perform a filter on each item.

```
observable1.flatMap { result1 ->
    observable2.flatMapIterable { result2 -> result2 }
        .filter { item -> !result1.contains(item) }
}.subscribe { println(it.toString()) }
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: And what if one of the observables is NOT emitting any items? This is only a problem when the table I'm fetching from the in the database is emtpy. The use case here is inserting new items into a database but checking against the what's already in the database...but if the database is empty..can I store perform the above operations you've suggested above?

Comment: @user1781538. Above solutions assume that the sources are finite. This is a valid assumption because in the question you said the items are emitted one by one. This suggests that the observables are finite streams, because otherwise there is no away you can compare the two entire sets of items. Even if the observables do not emit anything, it will still work as long as the observables complete.